# Copying excel row from one sheet to another

Tags: vba, excel

I am copying data from one sheet to another, from source range(Q5:AIxxx) to destination range(C6:Uxxx)

My VBA code starts with a cell and loops to the end of the column to finish copying that column's data:

```
Set s = Worksheets("Source")
Set d = Worksheets("Destination")

Dim i As Integer, j As Integer

j = 6
For i = 5 To 1500
   If s.Cells(i, 1).Value = "a" Or s.Cells(i, 1).Value = "b" Then
      d.Cells(j, 3).Value = s.Cells(i, 17).Value       
      j = j + 1
   End If
Next i
```

I have > 20 columns to move, is there a way I can copy the row at once? something like this:

```
d.Cells(j, 3:21).Value = s.Cells(i, 17:35).Value
```

At the moment, I'm having to specify each column:

```
 d.Cells(j, 3).Value = s.Cells(i, 17).Value    'column 1
 d.Cells(j, 4).Value = s.Cells(i, 18).Value    'column 2
 d.Cells(j, 5).Value = s.Cells(i, 19).Value    'column 3
 etc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by

```
    d.range(d.cells(j,3), d.cells(j,21)).copy
 s.range(s.cells(i,17), s.cells(i,35)).pastespecial xlvalues
```

Comment: Why use cells in range and not the range you want as String directly???

Comment: I didn't understand what you meant. or I dont know what you mean :D

Comment: Blenikos, cells in range is useful here, allows me to use J to loop. Thanks Ali

Comment: Why not create the string range using only range and not cells? For example you can do "A"+Cstr(i)+":"+.... Try to keep things as simple as you can.

Comment: you mean like range("A"&i":E"&j) ? @Blenikos

Comment: Yes exactly. But put i and j in Cstr() to make them from numbers into strings. I am not sure if it works by direct adding... maybe it does.

Comment: It works when range("A"&i). I havent tried the other one. Thanks for advice. I havent heard of Cstr before. thanks. @Blenikos

Comment: You are right. It works if you use '&' and variables (in this case i or j). It doesn't if you directly try to concatanate string and a number this way. Cstr() stands for create string. Is standard in most programming languages!

Comment: I only know some vba and R. So maybe thats why I wasnt familiar with cstr before :)

Comment: I've chosen this as it directly answers my question. Thanks everyone for alternative ways of achieving this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
.Range(<your_range>).copy
```

For example do:

```
Activesheet.Range("A1:B10").Copy
```

and thenjust paste anywhere you want with .Paste

```
ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Worksheets(2).Range("D1:D5")
```

It's a build in function in vba.
See here also for copying Range:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837760.aspx

And for Paste:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821951.aspx

Comment: However you could just transfer the cell values if the ranges much. Why copy? Copy-paste uses much more resources and will really decrease performance in your macros if you overdoing it.

Comment: Blenikos, how do I do this, was my original code copy/transfer or transfer?

Comment: Try this: worksheets(2).Range("A1:A2").value = activesheet.range("A1:A5").value No copy is required then. Is really faster in terms of resources used.

Comment: In bigger excel files you will notice huge delays if you use a lot of copy paste. I mean delays counted in minutes. I learned that the hard way actually.

Answer (score 1):

Using ranges instead can make it a bit easier:

```
Dim s As Range, d As Range
Set d = Worksheets("Destination").Cells(6, 15) ' notice the column 15

For Each s in Worksheets("Source").Range("A5:A1500")
   If s = "a" Or s = "b" Then
      d(,3) = s(,3)
      d(,4) = s(,4)
      ' or d(,3).Resize(,19) = s(,3).Resize(,19) ' .Value optional
      Set d = d.Offset(1) ' move to next row
   End If
Next
```

There are easier ways to do that without VBA. For example Power Query, PivotTable, Copy Link and Table Filter, Data tab > From Access, etc.